# Use superscripts in R axis labels

Tags: r

Using base graphics in R, how can I add superscripts to axis labels, as one might want to when plotting latitude and longitude axes on a map.

Consider this example:

```
plot(-100:-50, 50:100, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", axes=FALSE)
axis(1, seq(-100, -50, 10), labels=paste(abs(seq(-100, -50, 10)), "o", "W", sep=""))
axis(2, seq(50, 100, 10), labels=paste(seq(50,100,10), "o", "N", sep=""))
box()
```

Produces a nice frame around a map.  It would be even nicer to make the degree symbol superscript.

This can usually be done in other plotting functions such as `mtext()` and `text()` using `expression(paste(...))` or `substitute()` but how to do it in this case?

Comment: Does this `plot(0,xlab=expression(paste('(SOC[',kgm^-2,'])'^0.25,sep='')))` answer your question?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It works the same way for axes: `parse(text='70^o*N')` will raise the `o` as a superscript (the `*N` is to make sure the N doesn't get raised too).

```
labelsX=parse(text=paste(abs(seq(-100, -50, 10)), "^o ", "*W", sep=""))
labelsY=parse(text=paste(seq(50,100,10), "^o ", "*N", sep=""))
plot(-100:-50, 50:100, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", axes=FALSE)
axis(1, seq(-100, -50, 10), labels=labelsX)
axis(2, seq(50, 100, 10), labels=labelsY)
box()
```

Comment: Text mark-up in plots is a bit of an obscure area of R practice.  It always seems to mess me up.  Thanks for this clarity.  It would be great if someone developed an in depth tutorial for this.

Comment: What character is used to indicate a subscript?

Comment: @npo: square brackets (see `?plotmath`)

Comment: This breaks on text; Example: parse(text="Frequency ((364 days)^-1)")
Needed superscript for axis title. No solution found myself.

Comment: `plot(0,xlab=expression('Frequency (364 days)' ^ -1))`

Answer (score 43):

This is a quick example

```
plot(rnorm(30), xlab = expression(paste("4"^"th")))
```

Comment: How would you write something not in superscript at the end, as in "4th moment" without superscripting the "moment"?

Comment: @TheThunderChimp Sorry for the very late reply. Maybe you've already figured out how to do this, but you can do this: `plot(rnorm(30), xlab = expression(paste("4"^"th", " moment")))`

Comment: I have the same puzzle....where do I put the ""  in this instance to have the -1 (only) in superscript? i.e.....                                                                                           
 + ylab = expression (paste("Ba:Ca concentration (μmol:mol^-1)")

Answer (score 4):

@The Thunder Chimp You can split text in such a way that some sections are affected by super(or sub) script and others aren't through the use of *. For your example, with splitting the word "moment" from "4th" -

```
plot(rnorm(30), xlab = expression('4'^th*'moment'))
```

Answer (score 3):

The other option in this particular case would be to type the degree symbol: ˚

R seems to handle it fine. Type Option-k on a Mac to get it. Not sure about other platforms.

Comment: This does not work for other symbols like Unicode superscript 7 (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2077/index.htm)