# Manually create plot axis with labels in scientific notation (labels differ from coordinate values)

Tags: r, axis-labels, scientific-notation

Short background: I'm trying to create a custom axis for a plot in R, where the axis labels are numeric but do not correspond to the coordinate values they are placed at. I want R to format the labels in scientific notation because right now they're coming out like "10000000" which is not ideal.

Long background: I am making multi-panel figures where each panel is a filled contour plot. The `filled.contour` function will not make multi-panel figures, so I am using `.filled.contour`, which eliminates the legend - so I have been making legends manually. I use `rect` to create a stack of rectangles covering the color palette and `axis` to label values on the legend. However, the labels on the legend are based on the z-values, not the y-values, so I have an axis with numeric labels that don't match the coordinates the labels are placed at. When I feed those numeric values to `axis` manually, it stubbornly formats them NOT in scientific notation, which is suboptimal when the values are in the tens of millions.

This is the code as it's currently written:

```
breaks <- pretty(limits, n = 6)
          
marks <- (breaks - limits[1])/(limits[2] - limits[1]) # y-values in plot region go from 0 to 1
          
axis(side = 4, at = marks, labels = breaks, las = 1, tick = T, pos = 1.21, yaxs = "i", cex.axis = cex_legend, tcl = tickle)
```

Previously, I just adjusted the y-values of the contour plot to span the range of z-values (`limits`), so that the `at` and `labels` arguments matched:

```
axis(side = 4, at = pretty(limits, n = 6), labels = T, las = 1, tick = T, pos = 1.21, yaxs = "i", cex.axis = cex_legend, tcl = tickle)
```

and when I did this the labels were nicely formatted in scientific notation. (I would have had the same problem with unformatted labels on the actual y-axis, since the labels and coordinates didn't match, but since the values on the y-axis just go from 0 to 1, their formatting isn't an issue.) For reasons I won't go into, it is now preferable to use the 'real' y-values for the contour plot, but this leads to unformatted labels on the axis for the color legend.

If I was just making a few plots I could create the labels manually, but I am making tons of these figures with all different legends so I need to be able to automate it.

Comment: This question will be substantially easier to answer with 1) working example data provided as the output of `dput(data)`, 2) working code you are using to create the graph, and 3) an image with a mock up of how you'd like it the final graph to look.  See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/) for more.

Comment: The `labels=` argument in `axis` accepts character vectors. Can you just format the numbers the way you want with `sprintf`, `formatC`, or `prettyNum`? Alternatively, this might help: [Use superscripts in R axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628547/use-superscripts-in-r-axis-labels).

Comment: @dcarlson - these functions were all new to me, but `formatC` worked perfectly. Thanks!